# Large Array Comparison

Tags: java, arrays, comparison

I have ~25.000 distinct names in an SQL database, and would like to perform edit-distance comparison on all of these in order to normalize e.g. John Doe & Jhon Doe.

When the db was only around 1000 names I used to store all distinct names in an array. Then I would use two for-loops on that array, thereby comparing each element in the array to each of the others. When the edit-distance gave a match of say >0.9 I would execute an SQL-query substituting one value for the other in all records.

With my much larger database this is not possible anymore. What would you guys do?

ps: I'm also curious about any multithreaded solutions to this because the process is taking ages now.

pps: I'm coding in Java

Comment: are the names in the same table? which function do you use to compare the names?

Comment: Can this be possible on DB side? If so, I prefer that. Otherwise may be something like fork/join concept may be useful.

Comment: It is basically one large array of names that is compared against itself. I don't think this is possible on DB side because I am calculating a metric over each combination of two names to see if they are similar (to correct misspellings etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about computing the [soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) of each of your names and possibly storing it in the database? You can even do that on DB side, for instance there's [a MySQL SOUNDEX function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex).

After computing the soundex of each name, all you have to do is group the rows by identical soundex.

EDIT:

If soundex is too coarse for your application, you can first select candidates by comparing their soundexes, and use your usual metric on each set of candidates.

Comment: I don't really fancy Soundex, but I like your idea of using it to select candidates. Especially since there is a mysql soundex function available.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way around pairwise matching: the way as efficient as it gets.

If you need to do your record linkage faster, try using a string distance metrics that requires less computations than the edit distance ([Bonacci distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonacci_distance), [Jaro–Winkler distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance), etc.)

You could also use another metric as a preprocessing step, and then compute edit distance to confirm or deny the match.

Comment: I am using Jaro-Winkler which is an edit distance ;) The problem is not so much in the time the computation of the jw-distance takes, but in the number of records. I'm looking for a way to split up the work in different threads for example

Comment: @Freek8 Oops, I thought [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) was called the "edit distance" (but Wikipedia says that I was wrong, there are many ["edit distances"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) out there). Anyway, you have N*(N-1)/2 checks to make regardless of your metric; the only thing that could make your process go faster is calculating the metric much faster.

Comment: what do you think of the soundex approach by ChrisJ? I could group all the records by soundex and only do JW-distance per group. Perhaps I could give each group a seperate thread!

Comment: @Freek8 I would give it a try and see how it goes. You may get fewer matches than with your regular edit distance, but I am not sure if you have much choice there.

Comment: thanks! with my old approach I get out of memory problems, or it takes ages. Im gonna try this.

Comment: @Freek8 You should accept ChrisJ's answer then, because he was the one to bring up Soundex. Good luck!